# How can I implement font with webview?

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch some HTML data from database in WebView and I am trying to implement some custom fonts from asset folder but WebView can't read fonts from asset folder

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.instructions);
        String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/Noto.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
        String pas = "</body></html>";
        wv.loadData(rec.instruction, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'feast';
src: url('fonts/feasfbrg.ttf');
}

body {font-family: 'feast';}
```

Then use the assets path as the base url:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",myhtml,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Then how can I call "rec.instruction" inside loadDataWithBaseURL which call my data from database

Comment: check out JSOUP library how to get data from html data

Answer (score 0):

To make debugging your css easier, you can put the css file in an assets subfolder and `<link>` it to the html code.

Then instead of calling loadData, use loadDataWithBaseUrl, being the assets subfolder the base url. Also put your fonts under the same baseUrl.

For example, here the base url would be assets/web:

assets/web/css
assets/web/fonts

You can prepare your html and css outside of Android without having to escape so much text. And then mix it in.